# Does sending an animal home have any adverse effects?

Tags: animal-crossing-pocket-camp

I have the maximum number of campers now, but there is a cat and I want it as a permanent camper.

I'm considering sending an animal home? Does this have any adverse effect? (Losing friendship levels, for example)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interchanging animals has no effects on friendship.

Animals that aren't at camp will just be in the rotation for showing up at the various areas.